# How to get all connected Sql Servers in Visual Studio Sql Server Object Explorer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

i want to develop a Visual Studio Extension.

Therefore i need all Databases that are connected via Visual Studio Sql Server Object Explorer.
I want to connect to some of them during my programm execution.

I already tried to get all connected databases via

`System.Data.Sql.SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance.GetDataSources();`

But the result is not the right set of databases.

If its possible to get all the information about the connected Databases my program should like:

```
var databases = GetAllConnectedDatabases();
foreach (database in databases)
{
   database.Connect(); 
   // do something
}
```

Is it possible to get information about all 
Sql-Servers i connected via Visual Studio Sql Server Object Explorer?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

We could retrieve related connections via [IVsDataExplorerConnectionManager Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.data.services.ivsdataexplorerconnectionmanager.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Here is a simple demo for your reference.

```
 IVsDataExplorerConnectionManager decMgr = (IVsDataExplorerConnectionManager)this.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(IVsDataExplorerConnectionManager));

 foreach (var conn in decMgr.Connections)
 {
      var state = conn.Value.Connection.State;
      if (state == DataConnectionState.Closed)
      {
          conn.Value.Connection.Open();
      }
 }
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But..
I am always getting 0 connections.

Comment: Please check if you have Data Connections on your Server Explorer.

Comment: I ensured, that the server / database is connected. 
But now i get an Build-Error The “GetDeploymentPathFromVsixManifest” task failed unexpectedly : (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42985554/the-getdeploymentpathfromvsixmanifest-task-failed-unexpectedly) ... No solution found yet, so i cant test at the moment. But thank you very much for your input.

Comment: Able to build again, still 0 connections in the IVsDataExplorerConnectionManager.Connections.
My databases are listed as connected in the Server-Explorer.

Comment: what kind of visual studio version you are using, vs2017 or others? My demo based on vs 2015 enterprise, it works.

Comment: I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2017
Version 15.0.26228.10 D15RTWSVC
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.6.01590

Comment: @ColeWu-MSFT the user is asking how to get the connections inside the "SQL Server Object Explorer" window, not from "Server Explorer" Window.  Is there any possibility? I also need the answer